Do there exist times when the word, "empezar" means something to do with an investment portfolio or money? In financial context, what is the meaning?
Considerando el siguiente enunciado:

¿Cómo una persona de 50 años, puede empezar desde cero su economía y tener éxito?


Traducido al inglés, tenemos:

How can a person of 50 years have the power to empezar from zero and retire from the work-force, or attain an exit?


¿Cuál sería el significado de de "empezar" en contextos financieros?
En inglés, tenemos las siguientes traducciones parciales y comentarios:


divy into pieces

to put in-place

in pieces

emplace (similar a "empezar" en sonido y ortografía)

prepare into smaller pieces similar to preparing a comestible fish (pescado o pez)

Exchange money for, as you would purchase a fish in a market.

to establish a placid, still, and un-moving edifice; such as a stone plinth, stone pylon, or stele

to (metaphorically) begin the production of a child by inserting the fish of man into a woman ... (insert pescados... inpez ... empezar)




Los matemáticos de habla inglesa, hablan de relaciones como...

"de muchos a uno"
"de uno a muchos"

¿Significa "empezar" dividir una cosa en muchas cosas más pequeñas? ¿Por ejemplo diversificar una cartera financiera? ¿Dividir huevos de gallina metafóricos en varias cestas en lugar de en una sola?
¿"empezar" significa fusionar carteras? ¿Comenzando con huevos metafóricos de muchas canastas metafóricas y finalizando con una sola canasta fusionada?

What you wrote below "En ingles, tenemos las siguientes traducciones parciales y comentarios:" is hardly understandable to me.

In English,  "how can a 50 year old person, starting with nothing, obtain success?"

@Gustavson i think the asker is showing that he did due diligence by researching probable meanings instead o just throwing the question for the community to resolve..  I think this is a great question, dotting all the Is and crossing all the T's

@WalterMitty its actually an idiomatic expression, which luckily has an exact equivalent in english. People doing translation need to be very careful to use the correct idiomatic exprssion, which often varies wildly from literal translation, because it will feel very awkward to the native speaker.

De hecho "Empezar dese cero" es una expresión idiomática en español, qie tiene una expresión exactamente equivalente en ingles:

Start from scratch

esto tiene mucho mas sentido en el contexto financiero y otros contextos variados, en lugar de centrarse en el significado de "empezar"
En este ejemplo, la traducción la sentirán incómoda en inglés, pues es muy próxima a la conocida expresión idiomática, pero no exactamente como la esperan escuchar, lo que puede proyectar una iagen de bajo dominio del idioma.

Actually, "Empezar desde cero" is an idiomatic expression in spanish, that has en exact equivalent idiom in english:

Start from scratch

this makes a lot of sense in the financial and other varied contexts.
in this case, the translation "to start from zero" sounds very awkward to english speakers, because its close to the native idiomatic expression, but not quite, which would convey a poor mastery of both languages.

In North America, both of the phrases "start from scratch" and "begin with nothing" are idiomatic expressions. Given that the number cero is closely associated with the concept of nothing,  "empezar desde cero" signifies something similar to "beginning with nothing"

La frase es clara.
Empezar es sinónimo de iniciar.

¿Cómo una persona de 50 años, puede empezar desde cero su economía y tener éxito?


How can a person of 50 years have the power to start from zero and have success?

Incluso creo (pero no estoy seguro) que con do puede tener sentido esa frase...

How can a person of 50 years have the power to do from zero and have success?


"init" is not a word in the English language.

Yo lo uso mucho en contextos de inicios de procesos de desarrollo de software, es posible que solo sea para el área de informática?? Es más, Google me toma como válida la frase "How can a person of 50 years have the power to init from zero and have success?" Imagen de Google y acá hay más sobre Traducción de "init" en español

Puede que sea una abreviatura que se usa en informática, pero no es un verbo en inglés.

Listo, lo he cambiado. Gracias, a veces uno usa cosas tan frecuentes que piensa que son las correctas. Muy amable

@Gustavson You wrote something like, "init is not a word in the English language. It has the power to be an abbreviation used in computing, but init is not a verb in English". I want to respond that when writing code for a computer, init is an abbreviation of initialize. La palabra "empezar" está relacionado con la palabra "inicializar".
